# Xe5 FireMonkey Mobile with Online Database

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I uses SQLConnection and SQLDataSet to connect online database on db4free.net
it's working perfectly in design mode but in my android device it's not working and screen still black without any life !!
Is there any other way to connect Online Database ?!

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of what you are doing ?

Comment: Do any android apps work on your device?

Comment: here my code:https://www.mediafire.com/?cij869wxzzhcyt6

Comment: my android is 4.0.4 (Ice Cream)

Comment: You are trying to connect to a MySQL database. That is not supported for Android in XE5. It is supported by the third-party Unidac components from devart.com